# HSBC Payment method for Ubercart

Tags: 7, ubercart

I am unable to develop this but was wondering if there is any modules out there or at least some guide to work on HSBC Payment method for Ubercart 3.x ?

Comment: Presumably you've seen http://drupal.org/project/uc_hsbc ? It would need porting to D7

Comment: thank you, yes that is for D6 but D7 (Ubercart 3.x) has completely different methods of payment and I am unable to develop that, was wondering if someone already done that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for generalized payment options [Ubercart CCavenue](http://drupal.org/project/uc_ccavenue) can help. On their official website they provide some economy plans as well, which is good for setting up basic payment modules in place.